# Scan txt file for multiple strings and save the following lines

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a problem that I am trying to solve, however, due to my non existing PowerShell knowledge it is proving to be harder than I hoped. So any help would be appreciated.

The problem can be simplified as:

1. Find a string in a txtfile
2. Extract the information on the row after that string
3. Store the information in a handle
4. Find a second string in the txtfile and repeat the procedure
5. Store both strings in a new file or delete everything else in the txt file.

I am then trying to do this for approx 20k files. I would love to have the information under their keyword and comma delimited so that I can import them in other systems.

My files look somewhat like the following

```
random words 
that are unimportant 
Keyword
FirstlineofNumbersthatIwanttoExtract
random words again that are unimportant 
Secondkeyword
SecondLineOfNumbersThatIWantToExtract
end of the file
```

All files are however not similar in terms of the row that the lines I want to extract are on. I would the output to be something like

```
Keyword, SecondKeyword
FirstLineOfNumbersThatIWantToExtract, SecondLineOfNumbersThatIWantToExtract
```

And done. I got this far

```
 [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$folder = 'C:\users\xx\Desktop\mappcent3'

 foreach ($file in ($folder.EnumerateFiles())) {
     if ($file.Extension -eq '.txt') {

         $content = Get-Content $file

         $FirstRegex = 'KeyWordOne
    (.+)$'

    $First_output = "\1"
    $test = Select-String -Path $file.FullName -Pattern $FirstRegex 

  }
}
```

Comment: How big are the individual files?

Comment: The files are around 1-2Kbs each, so they are not that big.

Comment: Do you know what version of PowerShell you have? `(Get-Host).Version`

Comment: Why use `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instead of just `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\mappcent3\*.txt"`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Surely this is code bit from the internet and _due to my non existing powershell knowledge_

Comment: @Matt I get the following result 
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do something similar to what you are asking. This requires PowerShell 3.0+

```
$path = 'C:\users\xx\Desktop\mappcent3'
$firstKeyword = "Keyword"
$secondKeyword = "Secondkeyword"
$resultsPath = "C:\Temp\results.csv"
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    # Read the file in
    $fileContents = Get-Content $_.FullName

    # Find the first keyword data
    $firstKeywordData = ($fileContents | Select-String -Pattern $firstKeyword -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch).Context.PostContext[0]

    # Find the second keyword data
    $secondKeywordData = ($fileContents | Select-String -Pattern $secondKeyword -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch).Context.PostContext[0]

    # Create a new object with details gathered. 
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        File = $_.FullName
        FirstKeywordData = $firstKeywordData
        SecondKeywordData = $secondKeywordData
    }

} | Export-CSV $resultsPath -NoTypeInformation
```

`Select-String` is what does most of the magic here. We take advantage of `-Context` which consumes lines before and after the match. We want the one following so that is why we use `0,1`. Wrap that up in a custom object and then we can export it to a CSV file.

### Keyword Overlap

Beware that your keywords can overlap and create odd results in your output files. In your sample Keyword matches multiple lines so the result set would reflect that.

---

If you did just want to write back to the original file you could easily do that as well

```
"$firstKeywordData,$secondKeywordData" | Set-Content $_.FullName
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Hi Matt, 
This looks amazing. Thank you for the help. I do however have a few initial questions. 

I'm trying to understand the code and hence running it step by step. I started by assigning the macro variables the correct values, I then altered  $fileContents = Get-Content $_.FullName to point to a specific file. Iran $firstKeywordData = (Select-String -Pattern $firstKeyword -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch).Context.PostContext

 it does however not give me anything nor does it stop running. Why? How can I see what the variable captured? I was thinking about a get-content of the macro.

Comment: It wont let me write anymore, but thanks again for all the help

Comment: You should not be altering the line `$fileContents = ...` That is what reads in each file during a loop pass. Should only have to change the first few variables. OOPS. I forgot to pass the data to select-string. Updated.

Comment: @bettingdelo I add anothed update to account for the arrays that sometimes get returned. Notice the `[0]` on the end of the select-string lines.

Comment: Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    # Read the file in
    $fileContents = Get-Content $_.FullName

    # Find the first keyword data
    $firstKeywordData = ($fileContents | Select-String -Pattern $firstKeyword -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch).Context.PostContext

    # Find the second keyword data
    $secondKeywordData = ($fileContents | Select-String -Pattern $secondKeyword -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch).Context.PostContext

    # Create a new object with details gathered. 
    $FirstKeywordData[0] + "," + $SecondKeywordData[0]
} > $resultsPath

Comment: @bettingdelo Cool beans

Answer (score 3):

The `Select-String` cmdlet has a `-Context` parameter that makes it easy to extract lines before or after the line on which there's a match.

You can use `Export-Csv` to export to the format you require (although with 20K files you may want to write directly to the output files)

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem C:\users\xx\Desktop\mappcent3 |Where {-not $_.PsIsContainer})
{
    $FirstKeyword = 'FirstKeyword'
    $FirstLine = Select-String -Path $file.FullName -Pattern $FirstKeyword -Context 0,1 |Select -Expand Context -First 1 |Select -Expand PostContext
    $SecondKeyword = 'SecondKeyword'
    $SecondLine = Select-String -Path $file.FullName -Pattern $SecondKeyword -Context 0,1 |Select -Expand Context -First 1 |Select -Expand PostContext

    New-Object psobject -Property @{$FirstKeyword=$FirstLine;$SecondKeyword=$SecondLine} |Export-Csv (Join-Path $file.DirectoryName ($file.BaseName + '_keywords.txt'))
}
```

Comment: This looks like you are aiming for 2.0 compatibility which is good. If that is the case I would deal with `-File` which is 3.0 stuffs